# Angular 12 - Navigate to a new route keeping the url of the old route

Tags: angular

I have a requirement, where if i am on localhost:4200/home and we get a specific error, i navigate to a ErrorComponent route without changing the url i.e keeping localhost:4200/home as url.

i tried using NavigationExtras and specified skipLocationChange as true but that clears the current route and does not show the new route in the URL but successfully navigates to the error page.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try loading the component using *ngIf directive as shown in the pseudo code below,

```
//routing.module
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "/home", component: HomeComponent}
];

//HomeComponent.html

<div *ngIf={{!error}}>

//code of home component goes here
</div>

<div *ngIf={{error}}>
   <app-error></app-error>
</div>


//ErrorComponent.ts
selector: app-error
```